# jquery append result the list of input button cannot get exact value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I append random list of button `<input type="button" />` with different value of id's for the uniqueness which come from loop generated something look like this:

```
for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
    var btn_list = '<input type="button" id="btn_id'+i+'" value="button#'+i+'">';
    $('.btn_tableform').append(btn_list);
    }
```

and the result of this forloop are 10 button with the name of button1 and so on... but my problem is i cannot get the correct value and my button click doesn't seems to work.

```
for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
  $('#btn_id'+i).on('click',function(){
     alert($(this).val());
  });
 }
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ca21h5hg/

Comment: Seems to work fine in dfsq's Fiddle, and that code is basically identical to yours. Is there perhaps something you're not showing us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an HTML string and append that all at once after the loop. Also use a common class so you only need 1 handler!

```
var buttonList = "";
for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
    buttonList += '<input type="button" id="btn_id'+i+'" class="button-list" value="button#'+i+'">';
}
$('.btn_tableform').append(buttonList);

$(".button-list").click(function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You click event won't work because your button aren't present on page load, they are create with your loop. You will need to use the jquery `.on()`instead of `click()` like so :

```
$(".button-list").on('click', function () {
        alert($(this).val());
});
```